# Wouldn’t life had been better if one suffers his prarabdh karma in the same life time

Tags: vedas, bhagavad-gita, philosophy, vedanta, karma

I am aware of the three types of karmas. But wouldn’t the creation be better if the beings experience their prarabdh karma in the same life time instead of the next life? Maybe in that way everyone would be conscious of their right or wrong doings. Just a philosophical thought.